# Как вычислить N-го знак числа ПИ без вычисления предыдущих?

Tags: числа, численные-методы

Что-то связанное с формулой Бэйли — Боруэйна — Плаффа.

Как бы реализовать этот метод на практике?

Comment: Все понятно, кроме одного: в чем суть вопроса? Формулы у вас есть, программировать умеем/учимся. В чем помощь нужна то?

Comment: В шестнадцатиричной системе по упомянутой [формуле](http://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/20010.5.shtml) похоже, и реализуется. Разберитесь, как математик, опишите последовательность, а мы, крутые программисты, напишем код, чтобы вы в каком-то там конкурсе попытались выиграть : )

Comment: формулы имеем. программировать умеем.
но вот только если углубитья в глубь вопроса,
там появляется огромная туча своих нюансов,
и "подводных камней".
с таким мат. описанием, что мне даже институтского курса высшей математики не хватает, чтоб разобраться.
а хотелось бы узнать, с чего начать и куда двигаться.

Answer (score 1):

Метод Бюффона(Монте-карло) попробуйте. Больше спичек бросили больше точность. Быть может бросить очередную спичку проще, чем вычислить очередной член ряда. Еще можно использовать грязный хак, вставить в память уже вычисленное кем-нибудь другим значение и запрашивать Nый знак оттуда, тогда вообще будет бесконечная производительность

Answer (score 0):

Из формулы и заявления "что можно вычислить без предыдущих" получается что k тый шестнадцатеричный знак вычисляется так:

```
4/(8k+1) - 2/(8k+4) - 1/(8k+5) - 1/(8k+6)
```

но вот мне не совсем понятно почему остатки то не влияют в итоге на другие знаки,
попробуем вычислить скажем 100 знак:

```
4/(8*100+1) - 2/(8*100+4)-1/(8*100+5) - 1/(8*100+6) = 0,0012....
```

Итого результат влияет на 103 знак... вот явно предыдущие результаты нужный.... т.е. один фиг чтобы точно вычислить k тый знак, надо знать результаты <k. Либо тут можно сделать с этой формулой какое-нибудь мега преобразование?

Comment: хм я конечно не претендую на истину, но разве то что после запятой переводится из одной системы счисления в другую также без проблем, как и то что после запятой?

Comment: Насколько я мельком уловил суть [формулы](http://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/20010.5.shtml), для вычисления N+1-го знака числа Пи требуется не более N раз добавить в сумму:

Pi = SUM<sub>k=0 to infinity</sub> 16<sup>-k<sup> [ 4/(8k+1) - 2/(8k+4) - 1/(8k+5) - 1/(8k+6) ]

Т.е. для 9-го 16-ричного знака надо сложить от 0 до 8, умноженную на 16<sup>N-k</sup> и делить на (8k+1), брать дробную часть после этого.
N таких сумм видимо дадут N+1'ю цифру (первой будет).

Не проверял - поверхностно перечитал их объяснение.

Comment: @rasmisha, а какая разница то? Число представляется в виде summ((base)^k * (цифра)) при этом разряды до запятой это k>=0, а после k<0. Я понимаю, калькулятор винды не умеет в шестнадцатиричной системе дроби рисовать, но это не показатель :-)

Comment: @sergiks, вот-вот, мне в связи с этим не понятно громогласное утверждение "вычислить без предыдущих значений"

Comment: @Чад причем тут калькулятор? попереводите разные дроби десятичные в двоичные 0.7 например (обратный перевод тоже может вызвать подобную проблему), поэтому я не вижу смысла того что в примере написана дробь в десятичном виде

Comment: @rasmisha, Вы про периодичность? Или что-то ещё? 0.7D = (7/A)H :-D

Answer (score 0):

Предыдущие члены не нужны, так как складывая разряды мы можем влиять только на старшие, младшие разряды не меняются. Но и поэтому нам нужно, кроме N членов суммы, посчитать еще Log<sub>16</sub>(N) членов, чтобы учесть их влияние на N-ый шестнадцатеричный разряд.
Где-то в просторах Интернета был найден пример кода, в принципе по нему понятен алгоритм, [ссылка на код](http://pastebin.com/b6Qah55w).